# Getting Link State ID from Network LSA Pyshark

Tags: python, networking, wireshark, ospf

I am trying to retrieve the Link State ID of a Network-LSA from a captured OSPF LS Update in Wireshark. Wireshark says the variable is ospf.lsa_id, however this gives only the first instance of the ospf.lsa_id which is in the router-lsa part of the packet. How do I specifically access the Network-LSA for its LSID?

I have tried using array access and Wireshark documentation, but some of their variables are off by a single _ or .

Here is a screenshot of what I want to access:

[image: OSPF in wireshark]

From testing, it seems that ospf.lsa_id returns the first instance of it (which makes sense) but I want to be able to get all of the LSIDs.

I will probably end up looping through since it seems lsa_id is a list.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you post an example capture somewhere?

Comment: Hi Kimi. I will work on getting a screenshot up. In text format:
In Wireshark on an OSPF update packet, in the OSPF layer, LS Update Packet, LSA-type 2 (Network-LSA). I would like to be able to access the Link State ID of the network LSA but am having a hard time without using a loop, since there is usually more than one LSA in the OSPF update.

Comment: Try running pyshark in json mode (json=True in the constructor) in an interpreter and then access the field (names might be a bit different, look at the field names at the bottom of wireshark when you highlight them. Also note that fields with subfields will usually be called <field_name>). It should show up as a list. You can also see all field names by running pkt.whateverlayer.field_names

Comment: I got all the fieldnames and did have to loop through the list to get them all. Is there a more efficient way to loop through live captures than "for packet in capture"? I think my program is missing some updates.

Comment: It's either that or capture.apply_on_packets(callback_func)